# Pushing to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I have a project which needs to be uploaded in Heroku. After creating the project by typing `heroku create <project-name>`, I am trying to upload it. So

```
git push heroku master
```

This gives me back the following.

```
Enumerating objects: 124, done.
Counting objects: 100% (124/124), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (112/112), done.
Writing objects: 100% (124/124), 2.12 MiB | 538.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 124 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.4
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: babel-plugin-transform-class-properties@6.24.1
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread@6.23.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: css-loader@0.28.4
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: enzyme@3.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: enzyme-to-json@3.0.1
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: express@4.15.4
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: jest@20.0.4
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: moment@2.18.1
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: node-sass@4.13.1
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: normalize.css@7.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: raf@3.3.2
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-addons-shallow-compare@15.6.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-dates@12.7.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-modal@2.2.2
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-redux@5.0.5
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-router-dom@^4.2.2
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-test-renderer@16.0.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: redux@3.7.2
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: sass-loader@6.0.6
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: style-loader@0.18.2
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's uuid@3.4.0 does not satisfy uuid@3.1.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: webpack-dev-server@2.5.1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.JchKs/_logs/2020-05-22T06_07_58_025Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to expensify-app-1981.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/expensify-app-1981.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/expensify-app-1981.git'
```

I removed the `node-modules` folder and installed everything again with `npm-install`, but still nothing. How to fix that error?

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Expensify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Theodosios Tziomakas <theoaristi53@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build:dev": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build:prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "3.0.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "raf": "3.3.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "15.6.0",
    "react-dates": "12.7.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "validator": "13.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are the only steps done, you have to add a start script to `package.json`.

Under "scripts", add a new entry called `"start"`, and set it to the command that starts the nodejs app, like `"start":"node main.js"`

Comment: Please check my updated question. I added the package.json file.

Comment: @Theo OK and when you first removed the node_modules package did you also delete package-lock.json?

Comment: I haven't deleted package-lock.json.

Comment: It's ok now. Error is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: yet that was it.